# echo $_FILES['data-file']['tmp_name']; die; file name is not printed if size more then 128M in PHP

Tags: php, tmp

I try to upload file of 300 MB. but not uploaded and now display any error.
variables value in php.ini file is

```
post_max_size 800M
upload_max_filesize 750M
memory_limit 2048M
max_execution_time  17100
max_input_time 17100
```

if i try to print tmp name of file by echo $_FILES['data-file']['tmp_name']; die; Nothing display page redirecto to home. but for less then 128M it show /tmp/phpShle like that.

Comment: As you can see you have upload_max_filesize 750M,you can't upload more then this.You have to modify this

Comment: set error_reporting(E_ALL);  to show the error http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php , check your apache logs as well as application logs if you have

Comment: Is this possible that the size of tmp directory on server is 128M. Because only less size file tmp name is displayed and more file size name is not displayed.

Comment: I tried error_reporting(E_ALL); Nothing show. page redirect to home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proble is solved. I need to set these variable on modsec2.user.conf file

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 1073741824
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 1073741824
```

This is a apache server file. and error was shown on Apache error log.

Comment: Thanks to all for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are on LAMP make sure you are editing right `php.ini` file. In LAMP you will find cli related `php.ini` and php-apache related `php.ini`. To make above scenarios of file upload possible, you will need to edit php-apache php.ini file which is in `/etc/php5/apache2/` and also restart apache service.

If you are on WAMP, it has only one `php.ini` and WAMP is automatically restarting services after editing file. So it should work.

-Or-

You can write a .htaccess file in web home directory.

> RewriteEngine on
>
> php_value post_max_size 300M
>
> php_value upload_max_filesize 300M

Comment: hosting server is linux. and all variables in changed in default php.ini file. i also checked these by phpinfo().

Comment: Nothing show in error logs only older error show [12-Mar-2015 06:26:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:

Answer (score 0):

Please write this on .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size           256M
php_value upload_max_filesize     256M
php_value memory_limit            500M
</IfModule>
```

This might help you. Cheers :)

Comment: and make sure the version of php in your server is above php5

Comment: Actually the post_max_size and all other variables are set in default php.ini file with updated size

Comment: This code in live server worked for me. Did you try this in your live server?

Comment: yes, But not work for me on live server, its only work on local server

Comment: if this did not worked in live then you have to look at your cpanel.

Comment: what i have to look at my cpanel. i also used recursive for php.ini. But file not uploade. only less then 128M file uploaded fine.